# Get drawable resource ID based on screen density using String

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

So far I am using this code to add custom ImageViews based on the String value:

```
RelativeLayout rl_dashboard = (RelativeLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.rl_dashboard);
            for (int i = 0; i < imageResIDs.size(); i++) {
                int drawableResourceId = mActivity.getResources().getIdentifier(imageResIDs.get(i), "drawable", mActivity.getPackageName());
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mActivity);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mActivity, drawableResourceId));
                rl_dashboard.addView(imageView);
            }
```

But this, as I suppose, gives me the highest res drawable, which is xxxdpi atm. Is there any way to pull specific density's drawable?

I am checking density using:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        switch(metrics.densityDpi){
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                break;
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                break;
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                break;
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
                break;
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
                break;
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
                break;
        }
```

And I will access my static value before pulling up the resource.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for `ImageViews` wrong size was the lack of `LayoutParams` which I have added with:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```